# Backbone.Model: Many-To-Many relation or a wrap an array to a collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I got a global User Object:

```
window.Session = new Session();
window.Session.fetch();
console.log(Session.toJSON());
```

Outputs:

```
{
    "username": "kyogron",
    "email": "some.email@example.org",
    "contacts": [
        { 
            "username": "joe",
            "email": "joe@example.org"
        },
        {
            "username": "george",
            "email": "george@example.org"
        }
    ]
}
```

I would now add and remove contacts just like if we would work with an Backbone.Collection.
Is this somehow possible that I wrap the "contacts" array in a Collection which provides the same methods but still makes the attribute saveable?

Regards

**UPDATE:**

Currently I try to figure out how Backbone's "set" works. When I have understood it I could check if we have an array and than instead of just, create a new Backbone.Collection.

Comment: I assume you talking about nested collections.  This might help http://stackoverflow.com/a/7289124/1043012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you talking about nested collections. For options on how to create nested collections see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7289124/1043012).

Comment: Hi, yes I will go a similar approach.