# Fetch a Backbone.Collection made up of other collections

Tags: backbone.js, collections

So I have a few types of data:

`Post`
`Project`
`Event`

And each of those data models have their own collection and a route to view them:

```
/posts    => app.postsCollection
/projects => app.projectsCollection
/events   => app.eventsCollection
```

Now I want to add another route:

`/ => app.everythingCollection`

How can I create a collection which displays an aggregate of the other three collections, but **without fetching all the post project and event data again**?

Similarly, calling `everythingCollection.fetch()` would fill the `postsCollection`, `projectsCollection` and `eventsCollection` so that their data was available when they were rendered independently.

The whole point being never to download the same data twice.

Comment: This thread may be helpful: [Backbone - Collections nested in Models](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7288475/722238).

Answer (score 1):

Your `app.everythingCollection` doesn't have to be a really backbone collection. All it needs is just **access** and **fetch** to other collections.

You can inherit the `Backbone.Events` to gain all the events facilities also.

```
var fetchedRecords = {posts: 0, projects: 0, events: 0};
var Everything = function () {}
_.extend(Everything.prototype, Backbone.Events, {
    fetch: function (option) {
      that = this;
      this.count = 0;
      option.success = function () {that.doneFetch(arguments)};
      if (fetchRecords.posts == 0) {
        option.fetchedName = "posts";
        app.postsCollection.fetch(option);
        this.count ++;
      }
      if (fetchRecords.projects == 0) {
        option.fetchedName = "projects";
        app.projectsCollection.fetch(option);
        this.count ++;
      }
      if (fetchRecords.events == 0) {
        option.fetchedName = "events";
        app.eventsCollection.fetch(option);
        this.count ++;
      }
    },
    donefetch: function (collection, response, options) {
      if (this.count <=0) return;
      this.count --;
      if (this.count == 0) {
        if (options.reset) this.trigger("reset");
      }
      fetchedRecords[options.fetchedName] ++;
    },
    posts: function () {return app.postsCollection},
    projects: function () {return app.projectsCollection},
    events: function () {return app.eventsCollection}
});

app.everythingCollection = new Everything;
everythingView.listenOn app.everythingCollection, "reset", everythingView.render;
app.everythingCollection.fetch({reset: true});
```

You will need to increment `fetchedRecrods` count to prevent fetch multiple times. 
Something like this. Code is untested. But idea is the same.

Comment: Would this fetch only the collections that have not yet been fetched i f he does app.postsCollection.fetch() and after that runs app.everythingCollection.fetch(), expecting that only projects and events are fetched?

Comment: I have edited my answer. Like others, you need to keep a fetch record somewhere. Check record every time when you fetch. If you think keeping a record is not a good idea, you can extend the backbone collection to make it do fetch only once.

Answer (score 0):

```
var EverythingCollection = Backbone.Model.extend({

customFetch: function (){

    var collections = [app.postsCollection, app.projectsCollection, app.eventsCollection],
        index = -1,
        collection,
        that = this;

    this.reset(); //clear everything collection.

    //this function check collections one by one whether they have data or not. If collection don't have any data, go and fetch it.
    function checkCollection() {            
        if (index >= collections.length) { //at this point all collections have data.
            fillEverything();
            return;
        }

        index = index + 1;            
        collection = collections[index];

        if (collection && collection.models.length === 0) { //if no data in collection.
            collection.fetch({success: function () {
                checkCollection();
            }}); 
        } else { //if collection have data already, go to next collection.
            checkCollection();
        }
    }

    function fillEverything() {
        collections.forEach(function (collection) {                
            if (collection) {
                that.add(collection.models); //refer this http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-add
            }
        });
    }
 }
});
```

use like below.

```
app.everythingCollection = new EverythingCollection();
app.everythingCollection.customFetch();
```

for other collections, check `models` length before fetch data. Something like below.

```
if (app.postsCollection.models.length === 0) {
    app.postsCollection.fetch();
}
```

Comment: Seems like a really hacky answer for something so simple.

Comment: This is not hacky way. Do you think so? :) If you need to introduce another collection like `app.commentsCollection` you can simply add into that `collections` array. It's just that simple.

Answer (score 0):

Store all necessary collections in an array or object at app startup, attach an event listener to each of them listening for the first reset event and remember the ones you fetched in a second array. If the route where you need all collections is used you can fetch the ones not found in the array for the already fetched collections:

(untested, but it will give you the idea of how i suppose to do it)

```
var allCollections = [app.postsCollection, app.projectsCollection, app.eventsCollection];
var fetchedCollections = [];

$.each(allCollection, function(i, coll){
  coll.once("reset", function(){
    fetchedCollections.push(coll);
  })
});

var fetchAll = function(){
    $.each(allCollections, function(i, coll){
       if( $.inArray(coll, fetchedCollections ) == -1 ){
         coll.fetch();
       }
    });
}
```

Do this in your everythingCollection and you have the everythingCollection.fetchAll() functionality you need. You could also override the fetch function of the everythingCollection to first fetch all other collections:

```
fetch(options){
  this.fetchAll();
  return Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch.call(this, options);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like [braddunbar's supermodel](http://pathable.github.io/supermodel/) or [benvinegar's backbone.uniquemodel](https://github.com/disqus/backbone.uniquemodel) might address your problem

It's also worth checking out [Soundcloud's article](http://backstage.soundcloud.com/2012/06/building-the-next-soundcloud/) (see *Sharing Models Between Views*) on building Soundcloud next. They have a similar approach to the above two plugins in solving this problem.